# Calling C DLL function using ctypes is not working

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, dll, ctypes

I'm trying to call a C dll I created in Python within Visual Studio on Windows.

Here's the header file,

```
#pragma once

#ifdef MYCLIB_EXPORT
#define MYCLIB_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYCLIB_API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

MYCLIB_API int PrintStuff();
```

And the source file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyCLib.h"
#include <stdio.h>

MYCLIB_API int PrintStuff()
{
    printf("Stuff");
    return 1;
}
```

I'm building 64-bit debug, I have MYCLIB_EXPORT defined in the preprocessor property.  I also placed the MyCLib.dll in the directory of the Python script.

I created a Python project in the same Visual Studio solution, and have the following code:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

lib = ctypes.WinDLL('MyCLib.dll')

#dll = cdll.LoadLibrary('MyCLib.dll')

print "Done"
```

When I run the script, I get the error: `[Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`.

Did I make a mistake in the dll creation or the dll loading?

Comment: My understanding is you must build your DLL to match the way the Python interpreter was compiled/built wrt  debug and release. This is because different C/C++ runtime are used. Try rebuilding a release version of your DLL (or using the a debug-built version of Python. I'm not sure, but you may have to built it yourself from source.

Comment: @martineau, thanks for your suggestion, I tried building the DLL in release mode, but still the Python script has the same error message.

Comment: Too bad. Regardless, what I said previously is true (and applies generally to any MSVS created C extension). What does the `%1` in the error message represent? When/where are you getting this message? Are you  using the same version of VS that was used to build your DLL? That is also a requirement because there are different C runtimes for the different releases of the IDE's compiler. Lastly, if you're doing a 64-bit build, it _may_ require that you also use a 64-bit version of the Python interpreter (I'm not sure about that one, though).